# How to get Profile Ids without SOQL query?

Tags: soql

I had the need to retrieve profile ids but i had reached SOQL limit , is there a way to retrieve profile ids without increasing the SOQL count?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I guess there is no way to retrieve all profiles without using **SOQL/SOSL**. However you can use **[Platform Cache](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_platform_cache_org_examples.htm)** to store data and later retrieve it. But still you will need **SOQL** to retrieve **List** of profiles and then put it in **cache**. Sample example would be:

```
List<Profile> profileList = [SELECT Id,Name FROM Profile LIMIT 100];
Cache.Org.put('light002.partition1.profileList', profileList);
if (Cache.Org.contains('light002.partition1.profileList')) {
    profileList = (List<Profile>)Cache.Org.get('light002.partition1.profileList');
}
```

Maybe if you could post your code, community would help you to optimize your code.

However, for accessing logged in **User** profile `id` you can use following methods:

For **Visualforce page** use: `{!$Profile.Id}`. Here is the [$Profile link](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_variables_global_profile.htm)

And for **Apex** code:`UserInfo.getProfileId();`

Comment: Thanks rohit , i 'am not sure but after some search found that we could use platform cache but wasn't able to formulate a working solution.

Comment: @RohitC I've updated my answer.

Comment: ok , i tried your approach and it helped in reducing the SOQL count. Thanks.

Comment: Nice! I didn't know about platform cache.

Answer (score 2):

You can also create a custom setting and store all the profile ids in the key of the custom setting. Since Profiles are not created/deactivated everyday, the custom setting would be easy to manage. You can also write a daily batch to keep the custom setting data in sync with the profile Ids.

Once you have the profile ids in custom setting, you can use `CustomSetting_Name__c.getAll()` to retrieve all the ids without consuming any SOQL.

Comment: Thanks Rajesh , but i wanted to use it in a test class. So didn't want to write a batch for just a test class.

Answer (score 2):

Custom settings could be an option but it is not best practice to store the Profile Ids in custom settings as it would cause lots of problems.  For example, if you have more than one environments,  the profile Ids will be different.

Thus we can go back to the question how/why the limit is reached.  There are multiple ways to avoid hitting limit such as bulktify the code, using @future etc